# Yacc for different data types

Tags: grammar, yacc

I am trying to write a grammar lets the user use the operation symbol they are used to for multiple calculations.  For example, A+B, where A and B are matrices, or numbers.
Here is the relevant part of the grammar:

```
q_term: fraction    
| q_term '+' fraction   {$$ = q_add($1,$3);}
| q_term '-' fraction   {$$ = q_sub($1,$3);}
| q_term '*' fraction   {$$ = q_mul($1,$3);}
| q_term '/' fraction   {$$ = q_div($1,$3);}
;

qm_term: q_matrix   
| qm_term '+' q_matrix  {$$ = qm_add($1,$3);}
| qm_term '-' q_matrix  {$$ = qm_sub($1,$3);}
| qm_term '*' q_matrix  {$$ = qm_mul($1,$3);}
;
```

It gives me a bunch of shift/reduce errors.  I think that is because it sees the operation characters in more than one place.

How do I resolve the shift reduce errors?

Edit:

Here is how the parser tells the difference between a matrix and a scalar

```
q_term: fraction    
| q_term '+' fraction   {$$ = q_add($1,$3);}
| q_term '-' fraction   {$$ = q_sub($1,$3);}
| q_term '*' fraction   {$$ = q_mul($1,$3);}
| q_term '/' fraction   {$$ = q_div($1,$3);}
;

q_matrix: '[' q_term    {qm_temp = qm_create();  qm_append(qm_temp,$2,'c');}/* new q_matrix */
| q_matrix ',' q_term {qm_append(qm_temp,$3,'c');}  /* add a number to the current q_matrix row */
| q_matrix ';' q_term {qm_append(qm_temp,$3,'r');}  /* add a new row */
| q_matrix ']'  {qm_finish(qm_temp); $$ = qm_copy_matrix(qm_temp);} /* close the list */
;

fraction: INTEGER {$$ = q_new($1,1);} /* this converts a lone integer into a fraction */
| INTEGER '|' INTEGER {$$ = q_new($1,$3);}
```

Comment: How does your *parser* know whether a variable is a scalar or a matrix? If you cannot know during the parse, you should not try to classify expressions by type during the parse either.

Comment: @rici I added that section of the parser to the question

Comment: Ok. That could be workable but obviously you have some problem in the part of the grammar which you're not revealing. Do you really not have variables in this language?

Comment: I haven't added variables yet.  I can post the whole grammar, I was just trying to not clutter up the question.

Comment: The shift/reduce errors show up when I have '+' defined for a matrix and a scalar.  If I use different tokens, then the error goes away.  However, I don't want to use different tokens for each different kind of addition.

Comment: I'm sure that's true. But it's a symptom, not a cause. We generally prefer a [mre] since that avoids the need for multiple requests for clarification. An [mre] is not necessarily the entire program; indeed, it shouldn't be. It's a minimal subset *which compiles* and which demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: Anyway, if you are planning on adding variables at some point, you will eventually have to deal with the question I raised in my first comment. How does the *parser* know whether a variable represents a scalar or an array? If you require semantic analysis to make that determination, then it is futile to try to distinguish expressions by type during the parse. Save yourself the trouble and do the analysis afterwards by walking the syntax tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a language without variables (a simple calculator, for example), it can be possible to distinguish expressions of different types during the parse, provided that it is not possible to automatically coerce (cast) one type to another.

But realistically, it's going to be a nuisance to repeatedly type matrices out in full every time. You and your other users will very quickly demand some way to save a matrix constant as a named object. If named objects can also be scalars, then you will either have to insist that the name of an object somehow represent the type (for example, a matrix might have to be written with a capital letter or some such), or more likely you're going to end up not knowing during the parse whether a name is a scalar expression or a matrix expression. And at that point, any complicated grammar you might have built to try to distinguish the two types of expressions during the parse will suddenly become pointless.

So my advice is to save yourself the aggravation. The initial parse should just build an AST of some form, and you can then walk the tree to perform whatever semantic analysis you require, including resolving polymorphic operators and inserting automatic coercions, if any.

---

#### Ignorable Appendix

Although there is nothing wrong with your grammar for `q_matrix`, it strikes me as a little awkward because it doesn't really represent the syntactic structure of matrix constants. I would have written it slightly differently (also using the semantic values to store intermediate results instead of a global variable):

```
q_matrix: '[' q_row_list ']' { $$ = $2; }
q_rows  : q_row              { $$ = qm_create();
                               qm_append_row($$, $1); }
        | q_rows ';' q_row   { /* $$ = $1; */
                               /* ensure $1.cols() == $3.cols */
                               qm_append_row($$, $3); }
q_row   : q_term             { $$ = qr_create();
                               qr_append_val($$, $1); }
        | q_row ',' q_term   { /* $$ = $1; */
                               qr_append_val($$, $3); }
```

In the above, I commented out both instances of `$$ = $1;`, since in the case of C language bison-generated parsers, that copy has already been done just before executing any action. If you change to another language, such as C++, you might need to include the explicit copy.

The code assumes that you have both matrix and row (or vector) objects. (Of course, a vector object could be a matrix object with one row, if you didn't want to go to the trouble of implementing two distinct types.) In the code above, a row is completed before being appended to the matrix; at this point, it is easy to check to make sure that the row being appended has the same number of columns as the accumulated matrix. I indicated this test with a comment, rather than try to suggest what action should be taken if the test fails.